# verb-ing modifier trouble

Tags: participles, participial-phrases, dangling-participles, absolute-constructions

I'm unexplainably confused about this topic.

1. What does the following verb-ing clause modify? (noun) researchers
   or (action) have sent?
2. How do we decide that? --> **very important for me**
3. Is there any source by which we can study over the topic?

> Searching for signs of life on Mars, researchers have sent many probe
>   rovers to the planet.

Comment: Have a look at Nordquist, Richard. "Free Modifiers: Definition, Usage, and Examples." ThoughtCo, Feb. 12, 2020, thoughtco.com/free-modifier-grammar-1690807.

Comment: Starting a sentence with a subjectless gerund clause, most people expect listeners to understand a missing _while_ or _when_ before the gerund. And they expect the subject of such a gerund to also be the subject of the main clause, which should follow the gerund clause immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Various grammars interpret this in different ways. Here a but a couple of them . . .

(Warning: grammar terms vary!)

**Adverb modifying verb**:

*Searching for signs of life on Mars* is a [reduced adverb clause](https://www.elc.edu/grammar-lesson-reducing-adverb-clauses-to-modifying-adverbial-phrases/). You can think of it as being reduced from a full clause like this:

> *Because they are searching for signs of life on Mars, researchers have sent many probe rovers to the planet.*
>   *Searching for signs of life on Mars, researchers have sent many probe rovers to the planet.*

The adverb clause functions as an adverb, so it's not (under normal circumstances) going to modify a noun. It answers the question of *why?* for the verb (or the whole independent clause, really): Why have they sent rovers? Because they were searching for signs of life.

**Adjective modifying noun**:

*Searching for signs of life on Mars* is a [participle phrase](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/participle_phrases.htm) functioning as an adjective. It may help you to think of it as being reduced from a full relative (adjective) clause like this:

> *Researchers who are searching for signs of life on Mars have sent many probe rovers to the planet.*
>   *Researchers searching for signs of life on Mars have sent many probe rovers to the planet.*
>   *Searching for signs of life on Mars, researchers have sent many probe rovers to the planet.*

In the end, you'll want to understand it as your own grammar source dictates, but at least this might help you with an approach.

Comment: So much thanks, but you make me more intricate because I don't understand whether it is adverb modifying verb or adjective modifying noun. Which one?

Comment: @itsnotmyrealname: You can prove it to be either. But choose the one your grammar book does.

Comment: Seems easiest to consider it a substantive clause serving as the object of a deleted/implicit preposition like *by* or *through*. Then that makes the whole thing something that's answering a "how" type question, an adverbial function. Whether this constituent applies to the predicate alone or to the entire sentence is open for debate, but it doesn't make sense to me to try to say that it applies to the subject alone. See also Dr Lawler's comment.

Comment: @tchrist: I agree that it doesn't make sense to say it applies to the subject alone, but so many grammars do indeed interpret it that way: "the participle phrase always functions adjectively." No wonder the OP is confused.

Answer (score -1):

It modifies the researchers. Why?

It's very simple. We see that the verb-ing modifier clause is "Searching for signs of life on Mars". The verb is "searching". Now ask yourself: **who** or **what** is doing the searching? Upon asking this question, we see that it is the researchers who are searching.

There's really nothing to study for over here for these types of questions. Just run through the same procedure every time: ask **who** or **what** is doing the verb. You'll always get your answer if you do that.

Comment: No, sir, you are wrong according to the answer key. Could you look at the image? --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/NE6oC.png

Comment: I think that answer key is wrong.